# how to show islamic calendar in odoo 10

Tags: calendar, odoo-10

[image: how to show islamic calendar in odoo 10]

As you can see in the above screenshot, there will be two date fields from which if you select the second date field it will open up the Hijri (Islamic) calender
please tell me how to make date field in islamic calendar in odoo 10

Comment: How about some research? https://www.google.com/search?q=datepicker+with+islamic+calendar

Comment: it does't work practically please some demo

Comment: it dose not work in odoo 10 python

Answer (score 0):

you Charge active Arabic Language

[image]

Select Arabic Language to your user.
[image]
......
[image]

Comment: i am trying you method but does not work please tell me some demo or code

Comment: it does not change date in islamic in custom module form

Comment: i am show only islamic date this process convert totally odoo in arabic language please sort out my problem

Comment: Try to log out and log in again and update the browser.